# MSAL Authorization Url shows already consented scopes again

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I registered an application in my Azure tenant A. This application can work as multitenant application.

Then, I created another tenant B. Then, as an admin of the tenant B, I wanted to give consent for `User.Read.All` to that application by using below url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=openid+profile+offline_access+User.Read.All&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https....
```

Above url opened a permission required pop-up which is like below:

[image]

Then as an admin of tenant B, I gave consent for that two permission.

Also, when I enter to tenant B account, I can see the application and my consented scopes which is `User.Read.All` and `Maintain access to data you have given it access to`.

[image]

Later, I want to give another consent which is `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` to that application.
so I use the below url to getting permission.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=openid+profile+offline_access+User.Read.All+Directory.AccessAsUser.All&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https....
```

However this above url show me again the descriptions about the `User.Read.All` and `Maintain access to data you have given it access to` although I have already given consent for them previously. I expected to see only the `Access the directory as you` which is description of `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

[image]

Does Microsoft has a solution for this? Or should I manage scopes manually by storing consented them so I don't use them again in the url? Also I still not sure that second manual option solve the repeatedly showing `Maintain access to data you have given it access to` problem for every incremental consent.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the steps as yours and reproduced it when calling with `scope=openid+profile+offline_access+User.Read.All+Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.

[image]

It seems that if calling the `/authorize` endpoint it will show the permissions of `scope`. So I tried to add `Chat.Create` for test.

When calling with only `scope=Chat.Create`:

[image]

When calling with `scope=openid+profile+offline_access+User.Read.All+Directory.AccessAsUser.All+ Chat.Create`:

[image]

But unfortunately, I don't find the official document about Permissions requested.

**Note:** [`offline_access`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access) is used for refresh_token.

Comment: So, same situation is occured for you also, isn't it? What should you suggest? Should I manually manage the scopes for creating the url by tracking the consented scopes?

Comment: If you just want to add the new permission to user consent, you could call with `scope=Directory.AccessAsUser.All`.